# Microsoft Office won't recognise my account

Tags: login, office365

I have just downloaded office suite on my computer - I got access to it from my university. It downloaded fine and the apps open with no issue but they won't let me sign in. I am trying to set up OneNote first as I'll use it the most. When I try to sign in it says that it cannot load my first Notebook and to sign-in using a Microsoft account or account assigned to you by a work or educational institution.

The instructions my uni have given me is to use my university email (which works when I access office suite online) but it sends me the same error message. When I try to create an account with this email it says it already exists. It's all a bit circular.

I've tried using the troubleshoot instructions my university have provided but they are confusing and not very helpful.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide us more specifics, saying you received an error, without giving us the exact error (English) makes it impossible to answer your question

Comment: You should contact your Uni help/support staff.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue juest occur with OneNote or with all Microsoft 365 apps?

Please go to Start menu > Settings Account > Access work or school, check whether you added your account.

Generally, Microsoft 365 is activated based on licensed account.

Unless you log your licensed account into Microsoft 365 portal and download Office to install, you do need to log in to your account to activate Microsoft 365 apps later.

I suggest you use this account log into My account, go to [subscriptions](https://portal.office.com/account#subscriptions), check whether there is Office 365 subscriptions with "**The latest desktop version of Office**".

If not, you may check your Office version again, and contact your school administrator.